# IFilter with Custom properties

Tags: com, windows-search, ifilter

I'm developing a custom filter to my file format. Everything works fine when I use any of system keys from `<propkey.h>` like `PKEY_Search_Contents`.

But now I need to have my custom properties to register and use with Windows Search. Imagine:

```
"SELECT * FROM SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file:C:/' AND Publisher.Item.CustomProperty LIKE '%Test%'"
```

I saw about Property Handlers and already tested. I used the `RecipePropertyHandler` project from Windows 7 SDK Samples. And when I searched with this code:

```
// get a property store for the mp3 file
IPropertyStore* store = NULL;
HRESULT hr = SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(L"SomePath",
    NULL, GPS_DEFAULT, __uuidof(IPropertyStore), (void**)&store);

hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

PROPVARIANT variant;
store->GetValue(PKEY_Microsoft_SampleRecipe_Difficulty, &variant);

//// very important undocumented method
store->Release();
CoUninitialize();
```

I receive the correct answer.

But I don't understand how to union `IFilter` with `IPropertyStore` to create my custom properties. To start my `IFilter`, I used the example from `Windows 7 SDK Samples`. I'm doing something like:

```
chunkValue.SetTextValue(PKEY_SearchContents, filtered.c_str(),CHUNK_TEXT, 1046, 0, 0, CHUNK_EOS);
```

I didn't found the link anymore anymore but I read a quote of msdn about you can't implement `IFilter` AND `IPropertyStore` together. It's that true? Talking in other words, I can't create a custom property?

I saw all links from msdn, like [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-3x-wds-extidx-propertyhandlers), [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-3x-wds-extidx-propertyhandlers) or any other.
I can do separate things but I don't know how to union both.

Any ideia how to implement?

**EDIT**

Im trying yet implement the PropertyHandler. My .propdesc file have this content:

```
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2006/propertydescription"
        schemaVersion="1.0">
  <propertyDescriptionList publisher="Microsoft" product="SampleRecipe">
    <propertyDescription name="Microsoft.SampleRecipe.Difficulty" formatID="{1794C9FE-74A9-497f-9C69-B31F03CE7EF9}" propID="100">
      <description>This property indicates the preparation difficulty of a recipe.</description>
      <searchInfo inInvertedIndex="true" isColumn="true" />
      <typeInfo type="String" multipleValues="false" isViewable="true" />
      <labelInfo label="Recipe difficulty" invitationText="Specify recipe difficulty" />
      <displayInfo displayType="Enumerated" >
        <editControl control="DropList"/>
        <enumeratedList>
          <enum value="Easy" text="Easy" />
          <enum value="Medium" text="Medium" />
          <enum value="Hard" text="Hard" />
        </enumeratedList>
      </displayInfo>
    </propertyDescription>
    <propertyDescription name="Microsoft.SampleRecipe.Keywords" formatID="{16D19FCB-7654-48AB-8057-DF8E51CC0755}" propID="100">
      <description>This property indicates the preparation difficulty of a recipe.</description>
      <searchInfo inInvertedIndex="true" isColumn="True"/>
      <typeInfo type="String" multipleValues="true" isViewable="true" />
      <labelInfo label="Recipe Keywords" invitationText="Specify recipe keyword" />
    </propertyDescription>
  </propertyDescriptionList>
</schema>
```

On Windows Properties:
[image]

I receive all informations from file... but when I try to search with Windows Search like:

```
SELECT Microsoft.SampleRecipe.Keywords FROM SystemIndex
```

Where directory='somedirectory'

I receive all lines empty... Any ideias why?

**EDIT**

I can see my properties on PropSchema:

[image]

I can use my Microsoft.SampleRecipe.DifficultyV2 on my WSSQL Query like:

```
SELECT Microsoft.SampleRecipe.KeywordsV2 FROM SystemIndex WHERE directory='C:\users\step\documents\rvffilter\'
```

But all the contents are empty

Comment: An IFilter understands a file format and associates properties (custom or not) to chunks. A property handler gets/sets custom properties from/to a file. Both need to be registered. They kind of overlap, yes. The first thing is to make sure you really need custom properties. Windows 10 has already like 1600 builtin properties. Next is to determine if you need both IFilter and prop handler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers#full-text-contents but in general you need just one not both

Comment: Ok, I see that. So I just need to set chunk with my new GUID and will works? Create a .propdesc, register and after my DLL with implementation of IPropertyStore?

Comment: @SimonMourier I need both because my software will use Windows Search to index contents and other stuffs. That stuffs are dynamic and can be N. I'm trying to prepare my software to create property handlers at runtime, register and make my IFilter recognize somehow

Comment: You can use Windows Search with only a property handler. Anyway, I'm not sure what's your exact question/issue.

Comment: But with only Property Handler I can have a indexer to use WSSQL to query something I want? My main point it's to index with Windows Search and have a possibility to query data from catalog and not search at runtime with WS.

Comment: If the prop handler is registered (and works ok, fills in properties, etc.), then the indexer will know how to extract properties from matching files (based on extension). You only need a filter in specific cases that are explained in the link I sent.

Comment: @SimonMourier I registered my custom property with .propdesc. On properties files everything works fine but when I use to search on WSearch doesn't work properly. When I try to find something with `SELECT Microsoft.SampleRecipe.Keywords FROM SystemIndex Where directory='mypath\'` I get all rows empty. But on properties of document are ok.

Comment: My goal it's to index custom properties and have a possibility to search on Windows Search. My IFilter works fine with my custom file with Full-Text-Search BUT when I try to set some chunk on `Microsoft.SampleRecipe.Difficulty` (from Win7 sdk) doesn't work.

Comment: Have you setup the propdesc with searchInfo elements? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/propdesc-schema-searchinfo

Comment: Yes. My example ite on post. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. yes, it seems ok. But just to make sure... you don't use an IFilter, do you? Because you shouldn't need it, at least for this test.

Comment: I registered another format without a IFilter, just a Property Handler, to be more specific the .recipe from MSDN example.

Comment: I tried, just for test, set the chunk text directly with my IFilter (I don't know if that make sense) but didn't work like:    `chunkValue.SetTextValue(PKEY_Microsoft_SampleRecipe_KeywordsV2, content CHUNK_TEXT, 1046, 0, 0, CHUNK_NO_BREAK);.` You have any ideia what Im doing wrong?